# Калькулятор на JS выдаёт NaN. Всего три действия

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор

Совсем нет опыта JS. Делаю супер простой калькулятор.
2 чекбокса у которых прописана стоимость. У одного чекбокса есть инпут с числом на которое результат этого чекбокса умножается.
И в итог должна попасть просто сумма общая.

Если по отдельности, отмечаю чекбоксы, то всё работает. Если вместе то NaN.

```js
    var rozetka = 0;
    var rozetkaCell = 0;
    var check = 0;



    $('.input__check').on('change', function () {
        check = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                check = Number(check) + Number($(this).data('check'));
                
            }
        });
        summ();
        
    });

    $('.rozetka').on('change', function () {
        rozetka = 0;
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                rozetka = Number(rozetka) + Number($(this).data('rozetka'));
            }
        });
        summ();
        
    });
    
        $(".rozetka-cell").change(function () {
        rozetkaCell = $('.rozetka-cell').val();
        summ();
       
    });



    function summ() {
        
        
     
        rozetka = Number(rozetka);
        rozetkaCell = Number(rozetkaCell);
        check = Number(check);
        main = rozetka * rozetkaCell;

        $("#itogo").text(check + main + ' руб.');
        
        
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
          

                <input class="rozetka" type="checkbox" name="rozetka" id="" data-rozetka="50" value="1"><span>Установка розеток</span>
                <input class="rozetka-cell" type="number" min="0" name="rozetka-cell" id="" value=""><br>
                <input class="input__check" type="checkbox" name="lystra" id="" data-check="200"><span>Установка люстры</span>

</form>
            <p>Итого: <strong><span id="itogo"></span></strong></p><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
```

Вы почему-то идете по всем чекбоксам, но не у всех них есть атрибут `data-check`. Цикл надо убрать, а две строчки внутри цикла - оставить.

```js
$('form input').on('change input', function() {
  summ();
});

function summ() {
  var outlets = 0;
  var outletCount = +$("[name='rozetka-cell'").val();
  if (isNaN(outletCount))
    outletCount = 0;
  if ($("[name='rozetka']").prop("checked"))
    outlets = +$("[name='rozetka']").data("rozetka") * outletCount;
    
  var fixture = 0;
  if ($("[name='lystra']").prop("checked"))
     fixture = +$("[name='lystra']").data("check");

  $("#itogo").text(outlets + fixture + ' руб.');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">

  <input class="rozetka" type="checkbox" name="rozetka" id="" data-rozetka="50" value="1"><span>Установка розеток</span>
  <input class="rozetka-cell" type="number" min="0" name="rozetka-cell" id="" value=""><br>
  <input class="input__check" type="checkbox" name="lystra" id="" data-check="200"><span>Установка люстры</span>

</form>
<p>Итого: <strong><span id="itogo"></span></strong></p><br>
```

Comment: А в чём моя ошибка? Где в моём примере так "неправильно" работает?

Comment: @Григорий  `$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {`

Comment: а не подскажите ещё, почему при смене количества бывает что не моментально пересчитывает? Это особенности JS какие?

Comment: @Григорий Это особенности `<input type="number" ...` в разных браузерах.